# A tool to create a color scheme for printing

Tags: color, print-design, color-theory, color-reproduction

I'd like to have a color scheme for **printing** plots, that would look 'nice'. So, I need as set of, say, 10 easily distinguishable colors that would stay different when printed.

If I use only four CMYK colors they are easily distinguished. If I print ten, like blue, light blue, green, lime..., they may turn out very similar.

What tool (something like Adobe Kuler) can I use?

Comment: Lots of other similar questions here. Search 'kuler' and see for yourself.

Comment: @Lucian The main words are 'for printing'. If I use only CMYK colors, for example, they are easily distinguished. If I print 10 like blue, light blue, green, lime..., they may turn out very similar.

Comment: You should turn gamut warning on and simulate the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a suitable tool: [www.colorbrewer2.org](http://colorbrewer2.org)
Initially designed for maps, it has *print-friendly* option.

Thanks to the [UX stackexchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/23876/how-to-find-a-color-scheme-thats-also-useful-when-printed-in-black-and-white) answer

Answer (score 0):

There is a scheme used by printers called "CMYK" test. 
They look like this 
http://www.iso12647solution.com/Colorsource_free_CMYK_SRA3_test_forms.htm